# radius of convergence of power series of z/sin z around 0

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm trying to find the radius of convergence of the power series of $\frac{z}{\sin z}$ expanded at 0.

I have that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{z}{\sin z}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-\dots}
\end{equation*}

I am struggling to find a way to show that the series $1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-\dots$ does not go to 0, which would show that the series above converges?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The radius of convergence is given by the distance between closest singularity and the point of expansion (here: origin). All singularities of the function are given by $\sin(z)=0$. $z=0$ is removable. What about the other zeros of $\sin(z)$?